# How to create a sub-category filter which depends on a category filter in Django admin?

Tags: django, filter, admin

in the list filter of a model in my Django admin I have a filter `Category`, and I would like to add a filter `Sub-category`, which values depend on the selected `Category` value.

How can I achieve this using `ModelAdmin.list_filter`?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class inherting from [SimpleListFilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) for the Sub-Category.

Inside the method `lookups` check if inside the `request.GET` there is the matching querystring for `Category`, if there is, make a queryset based on this filter.

Should look something like that: (change according to your real models..might have syntax error, I didn't test the code, but it should look very similar)

```
class SubCategoryFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'sub category'
    parameter_name = 'sub_category'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        sub_categories = Category.objects;
        if 'category' in request.GET:
             sub_categories = sub_categories.filter(main_category=request.GET['category'])
        return (
            (sub_cat.pk,sub_cat.text) for sub_cat in sub_categories
        )
```

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question/answer, but I believe it should be `Category.objects.all()` instead of `Category.objects`. Otherwise, you'll get an error like 'Manager object is not iterable'.

Comment: Anyone has the error free version of this code? Django 3.2